# Solve a differential equation and evaluate the solution at a particular value of independent variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=(2-3i)y(x)$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$, what is the value of $y(\pi)$?

Comment: Show us what you tried so we can help you along...

Comment: Pleaseread about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 2):

It is a separable OE. Indeed, $$\frac{dy}{y}=zdx$$ in which $z=2-3i$. So $\ln|y|=zx+C_1$ for some constant $C_1$. Now find your $y(\pi)$.

Comment: Helpfull. $$+^{+}1$$

Comment: Thanks Sami, Thanks Adi. :-)